# Convert Range<Int> to swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, nsrange

I am trying to convert this code block to work in swift 3.

```
let grainSize = CGFloat(0.01)
    let min = CGFloat(-3)
    let max = CGFloat(3)
    let range = Range<Int>(start: Int(min/grainSize), end: Int(max/grainSize))
```

The issue I am facing is with the Range - I have tried to look through apple docs, but don't really know what I'm even looking for. The issue that it reports is that it says that
`Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange')`

Can anyone help help me understand what is going on here and where/what documentation I can read to make sense of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more powerful `Countable` range with more simple syntax:

`let range = (Int(min/grainSize)..<Int(max/grainSize))`

It returns [`CountableRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/countablerange), not just [`Range`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range), so you can access to [`RandomAccessCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomaccesscollection) methods, for example.

And if you want to get only `Range` value you can cast it like this:

`let range = Range(Int(min/grainSize)..<Int(max/grainSize))`

Also [helpful post](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/09/swift-3-ranges/) about ranges in swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Swift 3, it will work. There are no `init(start: end:)` method in `Range`. That is the reason for this error.

```
let grainSize = CGFloat(0.01)
let min = CGFloat(-3)
let max = CGFloat(3)
let range = Range<Int>(uncheckedBounds: (lower: Int(min/grainSize), upper: Int(max/grainSize)))
```

This creates following range:

> -300..<300

Comment: By the way, I dont get the error mentioned in question. For me it clearly says, there are no initializer of type `(start:Int, end:Int)` in `Range<Int>`. Most probably the error mentioned occurred at some other line of code which is not shared in question. But in any case, the above answer should fix the error since now you have a valid `range`.

Comment: In case you want to convert to `NSRange`, you can use `NSRange(range)` to convert `Range<Int>`